# Get data with relation using two columns in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a table named as users:

```
id |  name |  email
```

and attachment table

```
id |  file_name   |  user_id  |  type 
1    filename1.jpg      56         7
2    filename2.jpg      56         7
3    filename3.jpg      57         7
4    filename4.jpg      56         6
```

I'm fetching data from users table like:

```
 $data = Users::find($id);
```

but I want to get attachment table data also with users table. But I want to match `user_id` and type also, where `user_id` matches and `type = 7` only those rows should return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create Attachment model `php artisan make:model Attachment`

Create a hasMany relationship to 'Attachment' at the 'Users' model.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Users extends Model
{
    public function attachments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Attachment::class);
    }
}
```

Then you can query like

```
$data = Users::with(['attachments' => function ($query) {
    $query->where('type', 7);
}])->find($id);
```